# Обособлять ли "по-твоему"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова

"Это по-твоему нормАльно?"

Вот стоит ли обособлять? Вроде логическое ударение не стоит на "по-твоему", но это слово ощущается синтаксически связанным со словом нормально, да и вообще оно смыслообразующее, я в него вкладываю "по твоим меркам". Так стоит ли обособлять? Благодарен за любые обосонованные мнения!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:  ***Это, по-твоему, нормАльно?***  В вопросительном предложении и при такой постановке логического ударения это **вводное слово с оценочным значением**  «по твоим меркам, по твоему мнению».

Решение кажется простым, но это далеко не так, ввиду **многозначности**  слова по-твоему.

**Пояснение**

1. В справочнике по пунктуации указаны два значения для наречия ***по-твоему***: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_919

(1) **делать так же, как ты:**

Как вести о дороге трудной,

Когда-то пройденной самим,

Внимаю речи безрассудной,

Надеждам розовым твоим.

Любви безумными мечтами

И я **по-твОему** кипел,

Но я делить их не хотел

С моими праздными друзьями (Некрасов).

(2) **делать так, как ты хочешь, по твоему желанию:** Нет уж, извиняюсь, не бывАть по-твоему!  Ладно, пусть будет по-твОему.

Оба значения относятся к действию, но в первом случае (делать, как делаешь ты) позиция наречия **ударная**, а во втором значении (делать по твоему желанию)  наречие может находиться **в ударной и безударной позиции**, а глагол иногда пропускается  (любишь, когда всё по-твоему).

2. Вводное слово ***по-твоему***  имеет оценочное значение –  «по твоим меркам, по твоему мнению, на твой взгляд, с твоей точки зрения», причем оценка может относиться к  действию, признаку, предмету.  Но оно, как и многие другие вводные слова,  имеет **парное наречие** с тем же оценочным значением, то есть не обособляется, входит в состав предложения и выделяется **логическим ударением**.

3.Таким образом, можно сделать  вывод.   Только наречие ***по-твоему,*** которое имеет значение  «по твоему желанию» и относится к глаголу,  может находиться в **безударной позиции** (не бывАть по-твоему), а в остальных случаях наречие только ударное.

4. **Это, по-твоему, нормАльно?**  В приведенном примере  слово ***по-твоему*** имеет оценочное значение,  и здесь возможны варианты:  (1) Это, по-твоему,  нормАльно?  (1) Это по-твОему  нормально?

Первый вариант  (вводное слово) стандартный и частотный, а вот для второго варианта (с наречием в ударной позиции)  больше подходит **утверждение, а не вопрос**:  *Это по-твОему  всё нормально,  а я так не считаю.*

Для вопросительного варианта ситуацию подобрать трудно.   *Это по-твОему (по твоим меркам) нормально?  А ты не пробовал узнать, что нормальным считают остальные?*

6. Из-за многозначности слова ***по-твоему*** часто допускаются ошибки, особенно при переводах:

**Вводное слово**: И кАк, по-твоему, я смогу за всё это платить? По-твоему, здесь жАрко? По-твоему, здесь чтО, Королевский Ботанический Сад? КтО это, по-твоему?

**Наречие:**  А ты любишь, когда всё по-твОему? Будь по-твОему, Эд.

**Два варианта**: А как это, по-твоему, вЫглядит? А как это по-твОему выглядит?

Answer (score 1):

В случаях с обособлением (и соотв. интонацией) и без него смысл может оказаться разным. В первом случае высказывание равнозначно такому: "Ты думаешь, это нормально?" Без обособления смысл другой (интонационно подчеркивается - как вопрос - "по-твоему"): "Ты говоришь, это нормально, - это твое собственное мнение?*